# Comparing similarity matrices over time

Tags: r, matrix

I've computed 4 different similarity matrices for same items but in different time periods and I'd like to compare how similarity between items changes over time. The problem is that order of items i.e. matrix columns is different for every matrix. How can I reorder columns in matrices so all my matrices become comparable?

Comment: Are all the column names the same?  Then something like `mx2[, colnames(mx1)]`, `mx3[, colnames(mx1)]` will order `mx2` and `mx3` like `mx1`.  If you don't have names you need some other way of knowing what order they should be in.  Look at `?order` and do something like `mx[, order(<your ordering vector>)]`

Comment: Column names are the same but not every column from matrix 'mx2' is present in matrix 'mx3' or 'mx1' and also matrices have different dimensions so this is not working, but thanks @BrodieG it'd be useful in the future. Maybe I should add all possible columns to dataset even if they are zeros before counting similarity matrices?

Comment: Yes, adding 'blank' columns is certainly one way to go.  Alternatively, you could create vectors of the column names and calculate which ones *do* match, e.g., `cn1<-colnames(mx1)` for each matrix, and then `intersect(cn1,cn2)` to get just the matching columns.

Comment: I haven't thought about 'intersect()', thank you @CarlWitthoft. I was trying to compare colnames using 'which()' but it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving comment to an answer:

For each matrix `mx_j`  create a vector of the column names:

`cnj<-colnames(mx_j)`

Then for any given pair of matrices j and k,

`colmatch<- intersect(cnj,cnk)`  will identify the common columns, and the analysis can be limited to that subset of names.